# Why is my SQL Server 2014 default instance not auto starting

Tags: sql-server

Why is my SQL Server 2014 default instance not auto starting? I'm on Windows 10 and all of a sudden my instance doesn't auto start anymore.

All I did different was install SQL Server 2014 on the default instance rather than Sqlexpress instance. Now it doesn't auto start. It is set to Log On as `NT Authority/NetworkService`. But I still have to start it manually as of recently. I'm wondering if it was an update or something.

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          12/20/2015 1:08:34 PM
Event ID:      7009
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      
Description:
A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service to connect.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7009</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-20T18:08:34.466215300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2675</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="672" ThreadID="368" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer></Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">30000</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)</Data>
    <Binary>4D005300530051004C005300450052005600450052000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Startup Type = 'Automatic' ?

Comment: Yes it is set to automatic

Comment: It's starting normal manually?

Comment: That is correct. I can manually start it fine.

Comment: There should be something in the event log if it failed to start or started then stopped.

Comment: @Rod: I have exactly the same situation as you: Win10 (all updates), SQLExpress installed as default instance. I set Startup Type= 'Automatic', rebooted and I see no issues. Look in event log.